What is a “proper systematic order listing”?
I have a paper under review at a journal, and in it I have included a table of all of the species which exhibit a particular behaviour. Species are grouped by Order, and then family, and then species. The table is in alphabetical order by Order, and then within each order alphabetically by Family, and then within each family alphabetically by species. A reviewer gave very few comments, and the most substantial was as follows:
follow a proper systematic order listing the species

What does this mean? That I order the table to have more basal Orders at the top? That seems faintly ridiculous, but I can’t think of anything else. Or is there some official way to list taxa in tables that isn’t alphabetical?

There are natural and unnatural groupings of species, genera, families, orders etc among each other. Multiple orderings may make equal sense but alphabetical is not an appropriate ordering.
Remember that all of these are just labels for different branches of a tree, but the tree is still there. So if you have species where A and B have a more recent common ancestor with each other than with C, ordering them as A B C or B A C is appropriate but A C B or B C A is not.
I'd interpret the reviewer comment as asking you to use biology and common ancestry to sort rather than the alphabet. It's possible they would prefer you even abandon entirely the concepts of Order, Family, etc, as these are now a bit outdated. But even if you are going to use them, you should sort by the relationships rather than alphabetically.

So if you have species where A and B have a more recent common ancestor with each other than with C, ordering them as A B C or B A C is appropriate but A C B or B C A is not. This makes no sense without using parentheses to denote the relationships! See my answer.

@Cheery It does, in fact, make sense. You should not place C between two more closely related species/groups. That's it. No parentheses needed.
